# change firefox icons

Tags: firefox, themes, icons, faenza

I am using ubuntu os 12.10 with faenza ambiance icon theme.
But with this theme , changed also firefox's icon theme . Is it possible to replace the icons with the default one ?

Here is a screenshot of how it is now :

[image: http://img846.imageshack.us/img846/5941/screenshotfrom201211140.png]

and i want it like this (ubuntu mono dark) :

[image: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/5941/screenshotfrom201211140.png]

Is it possible to change them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icons you have indicated are called, from left to right, `go-previous.xxx`, `go-next.xxx`, `go-home.xxx` and `view.refresh.xxx` (or `document.revert.xxx`) where **xxx** would be the image format (typically `png` or `svg`). I'm assuming the icons are named according to [this](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).

What you have to do is to locate where these icons are: at a system-wide level they would be in `/usr/share/icons/name_of_icon_theme/`. At the user level, they will be in `~/.icons/name_of_icon_theme` **if** you have created such a folder. Within the particular folder, you may need to look in the subfolder called **actions**. Within actions, the icons maybe in `/16` or `/22` or `/24`, etc. (At least one theme has the size first and then actions as a subfolder.) For me, the icons are spread over /16 and /22.

Depending on whether the icons you wish to replace are in `/usr/share/icons` or in `~/.icons` you will need to use **sudo**. First, rename the icons you think you want to replace, then copy over the icons from the source you desire. You need to make sure they're the same size (16, 22, 24, whatever) and the same format. And ignore the ones represented by logical links.

To see if the changes are indeed the ones you want, you need to change to another icon theme and then back to your desired theme to effect the changes (using something like Ubuntu Tweaks or MyUnity or Gnome Tweak tool). Alternatively, you can log out and log in.

So long as you're systematic, nothing will go wrong and you can always revert the changes.

Also, all apps that use these icons will be affected, not just Firefox!